# How can i populate a treeview by ID and parentID using OLEDB

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, treeview, oledb

I have a big problem. I want to populate a treeview by some data i got.

There is a root node. To this rootnode i want to add some other nodes, defined by my data. The data includes a name, an ID and a ParentID

The data is stored in an OLEDB but i already have stored in my programm too.

Let me give you an example because my english isn't the best:

Data:

Testdata 1 0

Testdata1 2 0

Testdata3 3 1

Testdata4 4 2

Testdata5 5 3

Testdata6 6 4

Testdata7 7 4

So my tree should look similar to that:

+Root

++Testdata1

++++Testdata3

++++++Testdata5

++Testdata2

++++Testdata4

++++++Testdata6

++++++Testdata7

Have you any idea how i can achieve this?

regards

Schlinger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a recursive method to walk the tree.

```
private void AddNode(List<Data> data, int parent)
{
    var parent = data.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == parent);
    var dataItems = data.Where(x => x.Parent == parent);
    foreach(var dataItem in dataItems)
    {
        AddNode(data, dataItem.ID);
    }
    Tree.Nodes.Add(parent.Name);
}
```

Comment: I have tried it in my programm but it doesn't work like it's supposed to be. All nodes are on the same level and there is only one level.

Comment: private void AddNode(List<GroupEntry> data, string parent, bool first)
  {
   var parentData = data.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsIn == parent);
   var dataItems = data.Where(x => x.IsIn == parent);
   foreach (var dataItem in dataItems)
   {
    AddNode(data, dataItem.OID, false);
   }

   _tvDatabase.Nodes.Add(parentData.Code);
  }

Comment: This is your problem:  data.Where(x => x.IsIn == parent);   You need to use a different property of GroupEntry on the lambda.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. With your solution i could finally find a way to do it :)